# Express API using babel, express app won't start due to wrong version of Babel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, babeljs

Error message:

```
[nodemon] starting `babel-node index.js`
C:\Users\Zara Gunner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:328
        throw e;
        ^

Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While processing preset: "C:\\Users\\Zara Gunner\\FYP\\fourthyearproject\\fourthyearproject\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
    at throwVersionError (C:\Users\Zara Gunner\FYP\fourthyearproject\fourthyearproject\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:78:11)    at Object.assertVersion (C:\Users\Zara Gunner\FYP\fourthyearproject\fourthyearproject\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:28:5)
    at C:\Users\Zara Gunner\FYP\fourthyearproject\fourthyearproject\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:251:7
    at C:\Users\Zara Gunner\FYP\fourthyearproject\fourthyearproject\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:22:12
    at C:\Users\Zara Gunner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:317:46
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (C:\Users\Zara Gunner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (C:\Users\Zara Gunner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Users\Zara Gunner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\Users\Zara Gunner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
    at compile (C:\Users\Zara Gunner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:103:45)
    at loader (C:\Users\Zara Gunner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\Zara Gunner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Zara Gunner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\_babel-node.js:154:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'BABEL_VERSION_UNSUPPORTED',
  version: '6.26.3',
  range: '^7.0.0-0'
}
```

Comment: is there a reason you can't upgrade babel to the required version? (By the way, why the vue.js tag?)

Comment: Please provide a minimal example, espacially containing your `package.json`. It isn't possible to help you without knowing your package versions and setup.

Answer (score 1):

I face same issue, what I hav done is as below

first check you global package list using

```bash
> npm list -g --depth 0
```

also check your project *package.json* file and remove *babel-<>* library and install *@babel/<>* library

you must have **babel-cli** and **@babel/node** pacakge globally

1. uninstall global package first, which were older

```bash
> npm uninstall @bable/node babel-cli -g
```

2. remove *package-lock.json* and **node_modules** folder from your project root.
3. install latets `@bable/cli` and `@babel/node` in global npm package ( note: install @babel/cli not bable-cli )

```bash
> npm install @babel/node @babel/core -g
```

4. in your project root directory , uninstall the older package of @babal/ and install latest. ( assuming library are in devDependencies section)

```bash
> npm uninstall babel-cli babel-node -D
> npm install @bable/node babel-cli -D
```

that's it.